# Jquery declarative

Tags: jquery

So I have come to need many times now the ability to define jquery selections for a context that does not exist yet.   What I would like to do is build a jquery chain up and execute them in some future context.

something like

```
var $future = $.future().find('.stuff').each(function(v) {
    // do stuff
}).on('click', function(e) {
    // stuff
}).hide();
```

and somewhere in the future be able to do

```
$future(ctx);
```

so you could pass this in to event handlers and such such as

This would be extremely useful for `$.bind` so you could bind a jquery selection to elements that don't exist yet and have it happen when it does exist.

show an element when it gets the class showme.

```
$.bind('.showme', $.future().show());
```

The last use that comes to mind is when your trying to make thing async in synchronous code. So that when the element exists you can go ahead and call it but the calling code does not need to know there's not a real context yet.

Does this exist? If not am I alone in the universe needing this capability?  If it does not exist, and I am not alone in the universe, maybe I'll take a stab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already implemented. I guess this is what you are looking for- https://github.com/furf/jquery-future

Comment: Awesome that exactly it, thank  you for taking the time to understand the problem and finding the solution.   Funny it looks almost exactly like I imagined.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any of that. jQuery already has event delegation to support handling events on elements that don't exist in the DOM yet.

Classic event binding is usually something along the lines of:

```
$(...selector...).on('click', doSomething);
```

This is easily read as "when any of the selected elements are clicked on, do something"

jQuery has an event delegation form:

```
$(...selector...).on('click', ...sub-selection..., doSomething);
```

In the event delegation format, the event is actually bound to the elements matched in `...selector...`, but only is triggered when any of its child elements that match `...sub-selection...` are clicked on. The check happens when the event is triggered, so new elements that match the selector will also trigger the `doSomething` function.

Comment: Sort of but event delegation only works for things that are actually events.   It does not let you build up call chains for when the events are actually fired.  That it would be nice be able to use jquery to build up a callback that would take the context as an argument.

Comment: @speajus, you build the call chain when the event is fired simply by calling functions within the event callback.

Comment: @zzzzBoz thanks, I know I can do that, however I don't have an event firing... so nothing to delegate to.   I am proposing this as a nicer way to write jquery callback and call chains, as a nicer way than defining function(){ $(...).doMoreJqueryStuff() } all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function like this

```
function doStuffLater(e){
 $(body).on(e,".stuff",function(){
   $(this).each(function(v){ /*do stuff*/ }).hide();
 });
}
```

and you can call later doStuffLater(ctx);

Comment: I know this, my current iteration of the problem  I am working on is converting some synchronous code to async, however the method recievers are expecting a jquery object obj.$el, however the nodes may have not been created yet.   I would like to be able to return obj with this.$el with a context that does not exist, but call the chain built up on it when it does exist.     Besides it being a nicer way to write jquery without having to do callback function declarations everywhere.

Comment: `$(body).on(e,".stuff",function(){
   $(this).each(function(v){ /*do stuff*/ }).hide();
 });`   this .on() takes care of that, on is called as live binding and even the dom is added later this binding will work

Comment: event you donot need to call a function later just use `$(body).on("click",".stuff",function(){
   $(this).each(function(v){ /*do stuff*/ }).hide();
 });`

Comment: yes, I know, you can pass in functions.... but why, if all your doing is passing the new context into jquery?   It seems much more reusable to be able to define a response ie.  `$.future().hide('slow')` , the way I imagine it working would be `$(body).on('click', $.future().css({}).show() )`   seems nicer than creating a call back function.

Comment: ya that is also correct but it would be like this `$(body).on('click', 'selector' , $.future().css({}).show() )`